# Sign up with Twitter Error. Could not authenticate

Tags: node.js, twitter, registration, socialregistration

I am trying to create a social registration system. So far I implemented the function for sign up with Facebook. Now, when trying to create the sign up with Twitter account, I implemented this:

```
var client = new Twitter({
    consumer_key: 'oN******',
    consumer_secret : 'Za****',
    access_token_key: '9*****',
    access_token_secret: 'N0*****'            
});

client.get( 'users/show.json', { id: '9***' }, function(error, user, response){
if( error ) { res.json( JSON.stringify( error ) );  return; }
```

I hardcoded my user id and my app id/secret, consumer key/ secret.

I keep getting the error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}' }
```

Why does this error appear and how to solve it?

Comment: What is the Node.js module you're using?

Comment: twitter. I required it at the top of this file.

I regenerated my access token and my token secret. I replaced them in my code and now it works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure, why I'm still having the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. I got back to my Twitter application on https://apps.twitter.com
2. At *Keys and Access Tokens* page, I  clicked on <kbd>Regenerate My Access Token And Token Secret</kbd> button (see below)

   [image]
3. I replaced them in my code

Now it works perfectly.